# Give user feedback in asp.net mvc just before json return

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to give user feedback before the json return. But it dosen't work.

Here is how my message UI is created

```
@{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css/messages.css" type="text/css" />
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("myDiv");
            if (x.style.display === "none") {
                x.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                x.style.display = "none";
            }
        }

        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#myDiv').fadeOut('fast');
        }, 5000); // <-- time in milliseconds
    </script>
    if (TempData["msg"] != null && TempData["msgType"] != null)
    {
        string messageTitle = "";
        string messageClass = "";
        string mainDivMessageClass = "";

        switch (@TempData["msgType"])
        {
            case messageType.warning:
                messageTitle = "Advertencia :";
                messageClass = "fa fa-warning fa-2x";
                mainDivMessageClass = "message-box message-box-warn";
                break;
            case messageType.success:
                messageTitle = "Éxito :";
                messageClass = "fa fa-check fa-2x";
                mainDivMessageClass = "message-box message-box-success";
                break;
            case messageType.info:
                messageTitle = "Información :";
                messageClass = "fa fa-info-circle fa-2x";
                mainDivMessageClass = "message-box message-box-info";
                break;
            case messageType.error:
                messageTitle = "Error :";
                messageClass = "fa fa-ban fa-2x";
                mainDivMessageClass = "message-box message-box-error";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        <div id="messageSection">
            <div id="myDiv" class="@mainDivMessageClass">
                <i class="@messageClass"></i>
                <span class="message-text"><strong> @messageTitle </strong></span>
                <span class="message-text">@TempData["msg"]</span>
                <i class="fa fa-times fa-2x exit-button" onclick="myFunction()"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Here is my httpPost where I want to fill the feedback messages.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Editar(gestionDeUbicacionesModel gestiondeubicacione)
{
    gestionDeUbicacionesContext gestiondeubicaciones = new gestionDeUbicacionesContext();
    bool status = false;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
            if (gestiondeubicacione.ubicacion_id > 0)
            {
                //Edit 
                var gestiondeubicacionesFound = gestiondeubicaciones.GetAllInvenotryLocation().Where(a => a.ubicacion_id == gestiondeubicacione.ubicacion_id).FirstOrDefault();
                if (gestiondeubicacionesFound != null)
                {
                    gestiondeubicacionesFound.armario = gestiondeubicacione.armario;
                    gestiondeubicacionesFound.cajon = gestiondeubicacione.cajon;
                }
            }
            else
            {
            gestiondeubicaciones.addInvenotryLocationToDB(gestiondeubicacione);
            TempData["msgType"] = messageType.success;
            TempData["msg"] = "Nueva ubicación agregada!";
        }

        TempData["msgType"] = messageType.success;
        TempData["msg"] = "La ubicación ha sido actualizada!";
        gestiondeubicaciones.updateInvenotryLocationToDB(gestiondeubicacione);
        status = true;                
    }
    return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status } };
}
```

In my cshtml here is where I would like to see my messagess

```
<div>
    @{
        Html.RenderPartial("messages");
    }
</div>
```

Here is what I was able to do so far in the jquery I added the following lines after the update is successful.

```
              data: $('#popupForm').serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.status) {
                        $dialog.dialog('close');
                        oTable.ajax.reload();
                        var x = document.getElementById("testP");
                        if (x.style.display === "none") {
                            x.style.display = "block";
                        } else {
                            x.style.display = "none";
                        }
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $('#testP').fadeOut('fast');
                        }, 5000); // <-- time in milliseconds
                    }
                }
            })
```

And here is the html for my test

```
<p id="testP">test</p>
```

When I save the message test appears however I want to have my custom messages UI that I have made in razor.

What must I change to be able to see the messages before the json return. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The context of your question is unclear. Please try to post a [mcve].

Comment: When your action return `JasonResult`, it means it't not returning a view, just retuning jason data to the client browser. THe client browser is also showing a html content which has been rendered in the previous request. So there is no usage for setting a server-side temp data. No one is going to use it and the rendered html in client browser, cannot benefit from it.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I understand what you are saying. Then how can I give the user feedback that the json went well with the messaging UI that I have made in asp.net mvc?

Comment: You return the json result. Client can use the result and show some success message, failure or something.

Comment: @RezaAghaei how can I return the message as json and the use it in my messaging UI

Comment: You can return any type as json result. I assume you send an ajax request to server and then you return an object containing some data to use in client side, as well as a message. So return it from the action and then at client side using javascript show the message and update UI.

Comment: I think your question is about an ajax call sending a request to server, returning a jason data including a status message and updating UI. Is it your question?

Comment: Yes that is my question and I would like to use my messaging UI is that possible if so how can I do it?

Comment: @RezaAghaei I realized that you needed my jquery to show or hide the message after successful update.

Comment: @JuniorCortenbach you need to show `placeholder text` before `response` came from server right ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `beforeSend` callback function which is called before sending request to the server. Below is the example code for the same

```
$.ajax({
    url: YOUR_URL,
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    beforeSend: function () {
        //give user feedback here
    },
    success: function (res) {
        if (res) {
            //you logic after receiving the data
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        //when any error occur
    },
    complete: function () {
        //called when ajax completed
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try Thread.Sleep or Task.AWait in C# side / Make J-Query Call Synchronous[It will wait until it gets response/perform operations], try it and mark this answer solved which will help others.